# Is there any information detailing Vecna's relationship with prophecy?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

Vecna is depicted in 3rd and 4th edition D&D as the god of secrets. Is there a information (ideally in official sources, but failing that in well detailed unofficial sources) that outlines Vecna's relationship with Prophecy?

Does Vecna's secretive nature abhor prophecy as a method of unveiling truth?

Does the riddle and potential misunderstanding inherent in prophecy appeal to Vecna as a form of comedy, or even as a method of separating the worthy from the unworthy?

Is prophecy something to which Vecna is indifferent?

Or something else entirely?

Comment: Prophesies are filled with vague and mysterious half-truths. I suspect they'd be up Vecna's alley.

Answer (score 1):

Look up Deities and Demigods. If prophesy is part of his portofolio then its part of him,
and if not then No (Will Edit when i can find my copy).

Personally, I say no.

Now, the justification as to why not: Prophesy is vague and unknowable; it gives hints but nothing concrete. Vecna deals very much with what can and is known.

Comment: The 3rd edition does not list prophecy as part of Vecna's portfolio, and lists it as an aspect of Boccob's. I would imagine that they are not on best terms (both having Magic and Knowledge in their portfolio, but Vecna desiring domination while Boccob is aloof). Putting that together, I would guess that Vecna's take on prophecy is something that can be twisted to conceal truth.